# Passing html in string in include

Tags: symfony, twig

I have the code below and I need to pass an html element (anchor) as shown. I have tried using filters like raw and escape but it always prints out the html element as regular text. I also tried setting a new variable that contains the same string text and passed that to testLink and then applied filters to it, but same result. Any ideas how to tackle this problem?

```
{% include 'example.html.twig' with {'testLink': 'Hurry, <a href="#">Click me NOW</a>'} %}
```

Comment: What does your included template look like?

Comment: @xabbuh it is plain html

<div class="col-md-4"><p>{{ testLink }}</p></div>

Comment: Where did you use the `raw` filter? In the included template or when including it?

Comment: @xabbuh I tried this   ... with {'testLink': 'Hurry, <a href="#">Click me NOW</a>'|raw}

Answer (score 2):

You cannot handle your problem in the template that is including the `example.html.twig` template as autoescaping will step in when the passed value is displayed in the included template. Instead, you will have to use the `raw` filter in `example.html.twig` (be careful with that solution though as the template is probably used in other places too which might not be safe).